# Dynamically Include Files From Different Folders

Tags: php, dynamic, include

I have the following script to do dynamic includes:

```
 <?php   
$_GET["page"] = (isset($_GET["page"])) ? $_GET["page"] : "home";

    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $pages = array('home', 'solutions', 'projects', 'about', 'contact');
    if (!empty($page)) {
        if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
            $page .= '.php';
            include($page);
        }
        else {
        echo 'Page not found. Return to
        <a href="index.php">index</a>';
        }
    }
        else {
        include("home.php");
    }
       ?>
```

What should I add to this script to be able to also include DYNAMICALLY files from different folders (e.g. I have an `index.php` page that is in the `www/mysite_folder` and I want to dynamically include  into the `index.php` the file `Adresses.php` that is in `www/mysite_folder/faq_folder`)? Note that by dynamic I don't mean the regular include (`include();`) but `<a href="index.php?category=faq_folder&page=adresses">Adresses</a>`.

Comment: Would you like the directory to be specified in the `page` parameter or rather just specify the file name and perform a search to locate it in a subdirectory?

Comment: I can't get the meaning of your question

Comment: @ Another Code, well, I'm pretty new to PHP and I'd like to use a secure and easy yet functional method but if you could give an example of both those methods it'd be super.Also if you could incorporate it with the script I provided it would be very nice.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I have a folder (let's say: mysite_folder) where I store the majority of pages, one them is the index.php in which I dynamically include other pages that store content, but in mysite_folder I have another directory (lat's say: faq_folder)containing a page which page I want also dynamically included into the index.php.

Comment: any reason you cannot keep all your execution files in one directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason for splitting executable files between directories.
So, if you can keep all the files in one, here is the code

```
<? 
$page = (empty($_GET["page"])) ? "home" : $_GET["page"];
$page = "includes/".basename($page).".php"; 
if (is_readable($page)) { 
  include($page); 
} else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
  exit;  
} 
?>
```

which is secure and automated.

Comment: Thanks Col. Shrapnel, I put some files in another directory because they are associated to registratiing and logging in new users: registration form, form validation, log in forms etc. that folder is called userregistration. And the forms from that folder are to be dynamically presented into the content section of the index page:)

Comment: why not to put all executable files in one folder and all forms and other HTML templates - into another?

Answer (score 0):

`require('faq_folder/'.$file_name);` But it is not very secured solution.

Comment: Are there any other more secure solutions?